# How to implement a RSS-feed as a source in Spring XD

Tags: xml, rss, spring-xd

I want to load RSS feeds using Spring XD for storage in Hadoop.
I use the following example: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd/wiki/Creating-a-Source-Module
I created therefore a feed.xml file in the directory [/usr/local/Cellar/springxd/1.0.0.M7/libexec/xd/modules/source]
and later also in [/usr/local/Cellar/springxd/1.0.0.M7/libexec/xd/modules/source/feed/config/feed.xml]
by copying the example feed.xml file of the github example.

The github example states that "This section covers setup of a local project containing some code for testing outside of an XD container. This step can be skipped if you prefer to test the module by deploying to Spring XD."

I want to deploy the module in Spring XD using xd-singlenode and xd-shell. So within xd-shell I tried to create a stream using DSL scripts such as

```
stream create -- name bbcfeed --definition "feed | log" --deploy
```

As a result I get the following error message:
"Command failed org.springframework.xd.rest.client.impl.SpringXDException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/feed]Offending resource: URL [file:/usr/local/Cellar/springxd/1.0.0.M7/libexec/xd/modules/source/feed/config/feed.xml]"

I checked the existence of springdramework.org schema's. They do exist.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I checked the existence of springdramework.org schema's. They do exist.

I presume you mean on the internet - the jar containing the schema (and classes) must be on the classpath. You need to add the `spring-integration-feed` jar and its dependencies to the `${XD_HOME}/lib directory as discussed in the documentation. You can also copy them to the module's lib directory.

The `spring-integration-feed` version must match the version of the other `spring-integration-*` jars.

You are also using an old pre-release milestone; I suggest you upgrade to the latest release: http://projects.spring.io/spring-xd/ (1.0.1.RELEASE at the time of writing).

Comment: Thanks. I upgraded to the latest version. Additionally I obtained the required spring-integration-feed-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar from a Maven Repository and saved it in the lib folder. It works. 

One remark: some sites publish a RSS stream with a URL beginning with "feed://" Within the DSL one has to replace this part in the URL with "http://". The "feed://" protocol identifier doesn't work.

Comment: That seems to be a [limitation of Java and/or the Rome library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047421/question-on-using-informa-rss-library); if you like, you can open an [Improvement JIRA issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT) and we can add the ability to fix up the URI scheme if necessary.

Comment: Hahaha, you're kidding I hope. But thanks for the invitation.